# How do I start a new Perl module distribution?

Tags: perl, module, makemaker

I'm trying to set up a large-ish project, written in Perl.  The [IBM MakeMaker tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-make.html) has been very helpful so far, but I don't understand how to link all the modules into the main program.  In my project root, I have `MANIFEST`, `Makefile.PL`, `README`, a `bin` directory, and a `lib` directory.  In my `bin` directory, I have my main script (`Main.pl`).  In the `lib` directory, I have each of my modules, divided up into their own respective directories (i.e. `Utils::Util1` and `Utils::Utils2` in the `utils` directory, etc).  In each module directory, there is also a `t` directory, containing tests

My `MANIFEST` file has the following:

```
bin/Main.pl
lib/Utils/Util1.pm
lib/Utils/Util2.pm
lib/Utils/t/Utils1.t
lib/Utils/t/Utils2.t
Makefile.PL
MANIFEST
README
```

`Makefile.PL` is the following:

```
use ExtUtils::MakeMaker;
WriteMakefile(
    'NAME'=>'Foo',
    'VERSION_FROM'=>'bin/Main.pl',
    'PREREQ_PM'=>{
    "XML::Simple"=> 2.18}, #The libraries that we need and their
                   #minimum version numbers
    'EXE_FILES' =>[("bin/Main.pl")]
);
```

After I make and run, the program crashes, complaining that it cannot find `Utils::Util1`, and when I run '`make test`, it says `no tests defined`.  Can anyone make any suggestions?  I have never done a large scale project like this in perl, and I will need to add many more modules

Comment: I hope for you that "Utils::Util1" and "Utils::Util2" are just example names.

Comment: They are just example names.   I haven't written all the modules yet that I'm going to need, but I wanted to be able to build something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this structure:

```
bin/Main.pl
lib/Utils/Util1.pm
lib/Utils/Util2.pm
Makefile.PL
MANIFEST
README
t/Utils1.t
t/Utils2.t
```

As ysth said, `make` does not install your modules, it just builds them in a `blib` directory.  (In your case it just copies them there, but if you had XS code, it would be compiled with a C compiler.)  Use `make install` to install your modules for regular scripts to use.

If you want to run your script between `make` and `make install`, you can do:

```
perl -Mblib bin/Main.pl
```

The `-Mblib` instructs perl to temporarily add the appropriate directories to the search path, so you can try out an uninstalled module.  (`make test` does that automatically.)

Answer (score 13):

<s>If you are just starting to create Perl modules (which is also Perl's equivalent of a project), don't use Makemaker. [Module::Build](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Module-Build) is the way to go, and it's now part of the standard library. Makemaker is for us old salts who haven't converted to Module::Build yet. :)</s> I'll strike that now that [Module::Build](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Module-Build) is unmaintained and out of favor; I still use MakeMaker.

You should never start off a Perl project by trying to create the structure yourself. It's too much work and you'll always forget something.

There's `h2xs`, a program that comes with `perl` and was supposed to be a tool to convert *.h* files into Perl's glue language XS. It works fine, but its advantage is that it comes with `perl`:

```
% h2xs -AXn Module::Name
```

Something like [Module::Starter](http://www.metacpan.org/module/Module::Starter) is a bit more sophisticated, although you have to get it from CPAN. It's the tool we use in [Intermediate Perl](http://www.intermediateperl.com) because it's simple. It fills in some templates with your information:

```
% module-starter --author=... --email=... --module=...
```

If you are doing to do this quite a bit, you might then convert that to [Distribution::Cooker](http://www.metacpan.org/module/Distribution::Cooker) so you can customize your files and contents. It's a dinky utility I wrote for myself so I could use my own templates.

```
% dist_cooker Module::Name
```

If you're really hard core, you might want [Dist::Zilla](http://www.metacpan.org/module/Dist::Zilla), but that's more for people who already know what they are doing.

Answer (score 9):

Might I also suggest [`module-starter`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Module-Starter/)? It'll automatically create a skeleton project which "Just Works". I learned what little I know about Perl modules organization by reading the generated skeleton files. It's all well-documented, and quite easy to use as a base for growing a larger project in. You can check out [the getting-started docs](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/PETDANCE/Module-Starter-1.52/getting-started.html) to see what it gives you.

Running `module-starter` will give you a Perl distribution, consisting of a number of modules (use the command line option `--module`, such as:

```
module-starter --distro=Project --module=Project::Module::A,Project::Module::B [...]
```

to create multiple modules in a single distribution). It's then up to you whether you'd prefer to organize your project as a single distribution consisting of a number of modules working together, or as a number of distributions which can be released separately but which depend on each other (as configured in your `Build` or `Makefile.PL` file) to provide a complete system.

Comment: Thanks.  I read through that and couldn't find anything about doing projects, only about making modules

Comment: Tim: I've modified my answer to clarify how distributions and modules can work together in Perl. Hope it helps? Please do modify your question or reply again if one of us is still confused :).

Comment: This seems like a really good idea, and I'll have to use it for my next project.  I already set up a makemaker project, but this answers my question a lot better than your initial post

Answer (score 2):

By default, tests are looked for in a top-level t directory (or a test.pl file, but that has some limitations, so should be avoided).

You say "After I make and run"...make puts things into a blib directory structure ready to be installed, but doesn't do anything special to make running a script access them.  (make test is special; it does add appropriate paths from blib to perl's @INC to be able to run the tests.)  You will need to do a "make install" to install the modules where your script will find them (or use a tool like PAR to package them together with your script).