# How do I compile c/c++ code from Module::Build for a perl module?

Tags: perl

In [this question about creating a new perl module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495685/how-do-i-start-a-new-perl-module-distribution), it was suggested to use [Module::Build](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Module-Build) for any new packages.

I'm unable to find any examples using Module::Build that also compile c/c++ code.

I find this surprising is this really is the goto package for future development. Am I just blind?

Comment: I wrote one ([`Sys::CpuAffinity`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Sys::CpuAffinity)), though I wouldn't necessarily recommend studying it or emulating it.

Comment: Looking through my `~/.cpan` cache, I also see [`Params::Classify`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Params::Classify) and [`Params::Validate`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Params::Validate).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That question is dated and the level of unrestrained enthusiasm that Brian shows for [Module::Build](http://p3rl.org/Module%3a%3aBuild) isn't really warranted — it *works*, and may be better for your situation, but it has its own share of problems, and currently is receiving only limited maintenance.

But to answer your specific question: if you have XS files, all you need to do is put the `.xs` files in the top-level of your distribution, and they will be built, without you having to tell Module::Build anything.

If you have additional `.c` or `.h` files (including [Devel::PPPort](http://p3rl.org/Devel%3a%3aPPPort)'s [`ppport.h`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?ppport.h)) that should be built together with your module, put them in a directory and specify that directory as the [`c_source`](http://p3rl.org/Module%3a%3aBuild%3a%3aAPI#c_source) parameter to the `new` constructor from Module::Build.