# Compiling c executables from a Perl Module::Build module

Tags: perl

In [this question about compiling c code in a Module::Build module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268903/how-do-i-compile-c-c-code-from-modulebuild-for-a-perl-module), it was suggested to use [`c_source`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::Build::API#c_source) to specify the location of the c/c++ source code.

This configuration option results in compiling the source to object files, and adding the directory to the linker's search path.

I would like to know if a similar configuration can be achieved, where all `.c` files are compiled to standalone executables, and installed next to the `bin/` scripts.

Comment: Module::Build has a scripts option for specifying the paths of scripts. Why not put the path of the compiled executable there?

Comment: Because the source hasn't been compiled yet.. The module contains perl scripts, perl libraries a c _*source*_ code. The build operation should compile and install the c executables

Answer (score 1):

You could check out the Alien:: set of modules, which do a superset of what you want I think. It looks like https://metacpan.org/pod/Alien::Base::Authoring is a good place to start.